# How to interpolate a general formula from a set of data in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am making an experiment and I got the following results as  X and Y. I also draw them in excel and it seems they Y vs X as linear. How can I interpolate a general function F(X) so that I can get the value of the function at any other X value? I do not know if that is doable in excel
[Here are the X and Y results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7NYP.jpg)
[Here are excel drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m03Xu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Since your correlation is linear you can just use SLOPE and INTERECEPT to get the Equation for Linear trending:

```
y = SLOPE() * x + INTERCEPT()
```

So the formula would be

```
=SLOPE(B2:B12,A2:A12)*E2+INTERCEPT(B2:B12,A2:A12)
```

[image]

---

You can also insert a scatter plot and plot the trend line showing the formula, which will put the formula on the plot.

[image]

As you can see the formulas in E5:E6 return the same numbers as the trend line formula on the graph.